# PHP regex: Matching all asterisk inside all ul html tags

Tags: php, html, regex, match

I want to remove all asterisks from a certain html document. But only those, which are inside an ul-tag. Some of those ul-tags also have a class.
After hours of trying myself I decided to ask.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Probably not the answer you're looking for, but still worth a read: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

```
<ul[^>]*?>(.*?[*]+.*?)*</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
For some reason nothing gets matched inside the ul.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need:

```
<?php

// a function to remove any asterisks from a string
function replace_asterisks($replace){
    return str_replace('*', '', $replace[0]);
}

$html = '* blah blah * * <ul>blah<li>*</li>*</ul> sad sad <ul>**</ul>';

// if found any <ul> with asterisks, pas the part to that function to remove asterisks from it
$html = preg_replace_callback('/<ul.*?>.*?\*.*?.*?<\/ul>/', 'replace_asterisks', $html);

echo $html;

?>
```